# ImportXML Google Spreadsheet from Google search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy rates, open value, high and low value from below link, however I tried importXML =IMPORTXML(C12,//span[@class="IsqQVc NprOob i83_sDegKkXU-zJFzKq8ukm8 fw-price-nc"]), but didn't get the result.

https://www.google.com/search?q=indiacem+share&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN821IN821&oq=indiacem+share&aqs=chrome.0.35i39j0j69i59j0l4j69i60.2607j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

someone please help on this.

Comment: It encountered [Error
Could not fetch url: https://www.google.com/search?....] which mean the google sheet can't access the link provided. It might be blocked by google.

Comment: is it possible for <https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/nifty-100/indexsummary/indexid-2510,exchange-50.cms>

Comment: Hi ! Yes it is,I was able to extract the links of the site you provided in the comments by using ```=IMPORTXML("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/nifty-100/indexsummary/indexid-2510,exchange-50.cms","//a/@href")```. However, I did not understand what you want to achieve by accessing to this XML. **Could you please provide a sample of your sheet to clarify more your question?**